# Google Map marker not returning its value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, webforms

Please consider the following codes:

In my .ascx:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblLng" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(5.4149253, 100.3407387);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    var yeri = event.latLng;
    document.getElementById('lblLat').value = yeri.lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('lblLng').value = yeri.lng().toFixed(6);
});

</script>
```

After dragging the marker around the map and submit,

In my .ascx.cs:

```
string lat = lblLat.Text;
string lng = lblLng.Text;
```

This 2 lines return null values. Can I please know what I've done wrong? It's just not getting the values from the Marker on the Map.

Answer (score 0):

The `label` is converted into a `span` and the html elements like `span` or `div` does not have `ViewState` neither the text/html of these is sent to server side. The `form` elements that are submitted are the `input` elements, and `hidden field` is one of them. The asp.net maintains `ViewState` of the hidden fields. I am afraid you have to use hidden fields to maintain the value of label between postbacks.

In your .ascx:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblLng" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
<!-- 1. Add hidden fields to store and submit the latlng values -->
<asp:HiddenField id="lblLatHidden" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField id="lblLngHidden" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(5.4149253, 100.3407387);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    var yeri = event.latLng;
    document.getElementById('lblLat').innerHtml = yeri.lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('lblLng').innerHtml = yeri.lng().toFixed(6);
    // 2. update the hidden fields via javascript
    document.getElementById('lblLatHidden').value = yeri.lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('lblLngHidden').value = yeri.lng().toFixed(6);
});

</script>
```

In my .ascx.cs:

```
string lat = lblLatHidden.Value;
string lng = lblLngHidden.Value;
```